# A sentence from a sport article

Tags: sentence-meaning

I'm reading [**the article**](https://www.rt.com/sport/350586-portugal-wins-euro-2016-after/) about EURO 2016. Here is the sentence I didn't quite understand:

> Nani, Portugal’s captain in Ronaldo’s absence, had his side’s best
>   chance of the half, blazing over when put through by a diagonal ball
>   from the back.

First of all, ***the had his side's best chance of the half*** sounds like some nonsense. I know all these words but what the phrase mean...?

Another one is ***blazing over when put through by***.
I'd guess that blaze over means here to kick the ball quickly through the whole field right to the opponent's side so attackers could score a goal. But the part ***when put through*** by really confuses me. What could it mean?

Comment: *Had his team's best chance/opportunity of the (first) half to score a goal*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your passage, there are several assumptions being made by the writer.
Let's take the sentences apart:

> had his side's
>   *had his team's*
>
> best chance
>   *best opportunity of scoring a goal*
>
> of the half
>   *during that half of play (sounds like the first half)*

the second sentence

> blazing over
>   *running quickly over*
>
> when put through by a diagonal ball
>   *when a ball was passed across the field through the defence*
>
> from the back
>   *from whomever was playing in the backfield*

You can see how this play unfolded in the extra time before the half [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XN6lLeDRFWY&t=48m50s).
The ball is being centered.
Nani is #17 in the center, in front of the goal.

Comment: +1 I wasn't  sure what *blazing over* meant. I was wrong.